# Divergence of magnetic field $B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, physics, dirac-delta

I have to show that the divergence of this magnetic field is 0. I can do this pretty easily using the divergence theorem; however, if I try using try computing the divergence directly $\nabla B$ does not equal $0$.
To solve it indirectly I used the definition that defines the divergence as the limit of a surface integral. I chose a cylindrical surface and then showed that the flux through that surface is zero as the field lines form circles.

Comment: Where is your work? This question can only be answered if we know what you did.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Well, to get the answer I used the definition that defines the grad as the limit of a surface integral. I chose a cylindrical surface and then showed that the flux through that surface is zero as the field lines form circles.

Comment: My main confusion comes from the fact, that the gradient explicitly calculated gives a non-zero answer.

Comment: Why are you calculating the *gradient* of a *vector* field?

Comment: Please add your work in the question.

Comment: @NinadMunshi sorry, I meant divergence.

Comment: I guess your B is in cilindrical coordinates, so that is the $\phi$ component. Have you written the divergence in cilindrical coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. If I understand correctly, then you are solving the problem of a magnetic field around a infinite conductor with current. Writing down the equation for the magnetic field circulation, you got the $\phi$-th component of the magnetic field (only it is nonzero), i.e.
\begin{equation}
B_{\phi} = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r},\\
B_{z} = 0,\\
B_{r} = 0.
\end{equation}
The divergence in cylindrical coordinates is as follows
\begin{equation}
\vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{B} =\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial(r B_{r})}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial z} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial B_{\phi}}{\partial\phi},
\end{equation}
which is in your case is
\begin{equation}
\vec{\nabla}\cdot\left(\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}\vec{e}_{\phi}\right) = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\left(\frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r}\right)}{\partial\phi} = 0,
\end{equation}
where $\vec{e}_{\phi}$ is the unit vector along $\phi$.